# How to forge my OS fit screen in Console/Video(protected) mode in kernel C?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, kernel

First of all, sorry for my English.
I'm creating my own operating system but I have some screen size issues.
How can I make my OS fit screen and get screen size?
Thank you all.

Comment: What is the "screen" here? Some hardware screen? A terminal? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OS is a huge thing with many pieces (boot loader, kernel, drivers, GUI, applications, ...). All of the pieces depend on lower level things causing "layers", where pieces at one layer (e.g. applications) depend on pieces in lower layers (GUI, VFS, network stack) which depend on pieces in a lower layer (drivers) which...

For any piece to be able to fit to screen size there are 2 options:

- provide resolution independence. This is most often used for higher level graphics (e.g. drawing lines, rectangles, characters, etc); where a lower layer (e.g. video card driver) converts from a virtual coordinate system into a physical coordinate system (the video mode's resolution). In this case the higher level pieces have no reason to care what "screen size in pixels" is; "screen size in virtual coordinates" may be constant (e.g. "from -1.0 to +1.0"); and "physical screen size in millimeters" (if needed) would have to come from lower layers.
- fail to provide resolution independence. This is most often used for crusty old bad stuff (and should be avoided) because it causes major problems - either graphics becomes awful (e.g. tiny fonts you can't read or huge icons taking up most of the screen) because there's a large difference between the screen size that the programmer assumed and the screen size that is actually being used; or programmers have to do a lot more work varying the size of all their graphics themselves (and most don't bother). In this case; both "screen size in pixels" and "physical screen size in millimeters" (if needed) would have to come from lower layers.

Note that for early boot (before you've started drivers, etc) "lower layers" can mean "firmware". For example; kernel might get "screen size" from boot loader, and boot loader might get "screen size" from whichever firmware functions it used to select and set a video mode.

Finally; for all cases, "screen size in characters" is an extra pile of problems (on top of "screen size in pixels/virtual coords/millimeters"). Because modern font rendering engines use proportional fonts (different characters have different widths) and support different font sizes there is no correct "screen size in characters" value. Instead you end up needing to query the font engine (e.g. "For this specific font at this specific font size; how many of the characters in this specific string will fit between this starting position and the edge of the screen"), and this kind of thing typically ends up being delegated to a "layout engine" (that determines things like word wrap and widget placement from a higher level/more abstract representation). Of course this is extremely complicated. However; there is one specific case (mono-spaced fonts at one fixed size) where "screen size in characters" can be determine by simple integer division ("screen size in characters = screen size in pixels / character size in pixels").

Answer (score 0):

The screen size is written in the specification of your screen.  Read the specification, write it into your OS and you are done.